# How to execute button.setOnTouchListener when some conditions are met (Kotlin)

Tags: java, kotlin

I made button and give it touchlistener.

When I hold it, function named "fun" is executed repeatedly with milliseconds.

But I want to add a condition in addition to holding button. (Just like "a == true")

when I write the code such as

```
if ( a == true ) { button.setOnTouchListener(RepeatListener(initialInterval, normalInterval, View.OnClickListener {
        fun()
    }))
```

and here is RepeatListener I found at this site.

```
import android.os.Handler
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener

/**
 * A class, that can be used as a TouchListener on any view (e.g. a Button).
 * It cyclically runs a clickListener, emulating keyboard-like behaviour. First
 * click is fired immediately, next one after the initialInterval, and subsequent
 * ones after the normalInterval.
 *
 *
 * Interval is scheduled after the onClick completes, so it has to run fast.
 * If it runs slow, it does not generate skipped onClicks. Can be rewritten to
 * achieve this.
 */
class RepeatListener(initialInterval: Long, normalInterval: Long, clickListener: View.OnClickListener?) : OnTouchListener {
    private val handler = Handler()
    private val initialInterval: Long
    private val normalInterval: Long
    private val clickListener: View.OnClickListener
    private var touchedView: View? = null
    private val handlerRunnable: Runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            if (touchedView!!.isEnabled) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, normalInterval)
                clickListener!!.onClick(touchedView)
            } else {
                // if the view was disabled by the clickListener, remove the callback
                handler.removeCallbacks(this)
                touchedView!!.isPressed = false
                touchedView = null
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onTouch(view: View, motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            when (motionEvent.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(handlerRunnable)
                    handler.postDelayed(handlerRunnable, initialInterval)
                    touchedView = view
                    touchedView!!.isPressed = true
                    clickListener.onClick(view)
                    return true
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(handlerRunnable)
                    touchedView!!.isPressed = false
                    touchedView = null
                    return true
                }
            }
        return false
    }

    /**
     * @param initialInterval The interval after first click event
     * @param normalInterval The interval after second and subsequent click
     * events
     * @param clickListener The OnClickListener, that will be called
     * periodically
     */
    init {
        requireNotNull(clickListener) { "null runnable" }
        require(!(initialInterval < 0 || normalInterval < 0)) { "negative interval" }
        this.initialInterval = initialInterval
        this.normalInterval = normalInterval
        this.clickListener = clickListener
    }
}
```

it didn't work properly..

How to write "when a is true, holding button excutes fun() repeatedly" ??

Comment: The onClickListener is a "listener", it must be set before the click event happen, probably you want to do an if check inside the listener itself.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem with writing something like

```
button.setOnTouchListener { if (a) fun() }
```

If you want to achieve behavior, such as "when `a` is `false`, execute `fun` once, you can also try adding

```
button.setOnClickListener { if (a) return else fun() }
```